# How to put a complicated equation into a R formula?

Tags: r, statistics, data-modeling, regression, linear-regression

We have the diameter of trees as the predictor and tree height as the dependent variable. A number of different equations exist for this kind of data and we try to model some of them and compare the results.

However, we we can't figure out how to correctly put one equation into the corresponding `R` `formula` format.

The `trees` data set in `R` can be used as an example.

```
data(trees)
df <- trees
df$h <- df$Height * 0.3048   #transform to metric system
df$dbh <- (trees$Girth * 0.3048) / pi   #transform tree girth to diameter
```

First, the example of an equation that seems to work well:

[image]

```
form1 <- h ~ I(dbh ^ -1) + I( dbh ^ 2)  
m1 <- lm(form1, data = df)
m1

Call:
lm(formula = form1, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    I(dbh^-1)     I(dbh^2)  
27.1147      -5.0553       0.1124
```

Coefficients `a`, `b` and `c` are estimated, which is what we are interested in.

Now the problematic equation:

[image]

Trying to fit it like this:

```
form2 <- h ~ I(dbh ^ 2) / dbh + I(dbh ^ 2) + 1.3
```

gives an error:

```
m1 <- lm(form2, data = df)
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) 
invalid model formula in ExtractVars
```

I guess this is because `/` is interpreted as a nested model and not an arithmetic operator?

This doesn't give an error:

```
form2 <- h ~ I(I(dbh ^ 2) / dbh + I(dbh ^ 2) + 1.3)
m1 <- lm(form2, data = df)
```

But the result is not the one we want:

```
m1
Call:
lm(formula = form2, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  I(I(dbh^2)/dbh + I(dbh^2) + 1.3)  
19.3883                            0.8727
```

Only one coefficient is given for the whole term within the outer `I()`, which seems to be logic.

How can we fit the second equation to our data?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you are using `nls` the R formula can use an ordinary R function, `H(a, b, c, D)`, so the formula can be just `h ~ H(a, b, c, dbh)` and this works:

```
# use lm to get startingf values
lm1 <- lm(1/(h - 1.3) ~ I(1/dbh) + I(1/dbh^2), df)
start <- rev(setNames(coef(lm1), c("c", "b", "a")))

# run nls
H <- function(a, b, c, D) 1.3 + D^2 / (a + b * D + c * D^2)
nls1 <- nls(h ~ H(a, b, c, dbh), df, start = start)

nls1 # display result
```

Graphing the output:

```
plot(h ~ dbh, df)
lines(fitted(nls1) ~ dbh, df)
```

[image]

Comment: I will mark this answer as the correct one because a) it includes how to estimate starting values, b) using an ordinary R function permits us to fit other non-linear function very easily and c) it plots the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You've got a couple problems. (1) You're missing parentheses for the denominator of `form2` (and R has no way to know that you want to add a constant `a` in the denominator, or where to put any of the parameters, really), and much more problematic: (2) your 2nd model *isn't linear*, so `lm` won't work.

Fixing (1) is easy:

```
form2 <- h ~ 1.3 + I(dbh^2) / (a + b * dbh + c * I(dbh^2))
```

Fixing (2), though there are many ways to estimate parameters for a nonlinear model, the `nls` (nonlinear least squares) is a good place to start:

```
m2 <- nls(form2, data = df, start = list(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1))
```

You need to provide starting guesses for the parameters in `nls`. I just picked 1's, but you should use better guesses that ballpark what the parameters might be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It would have taken us ages to discover those problems and even longer to find a solution.

Answer (score 10):

**edit**: **fixed, no longer incorrectly using offset ...**

An answer that complements @shujaa's:

You can transform your problem from

```
H = 1.3 + D^2/(a+b*D+c*D^2)
```

to

```
1/(H-1.3) = a/D^2+b/D+c
```

This would normally mess up the assumptions of the model (i.e., if `H` were normally distributed with constant variance, then `1/(H-1.3)` wouldn't be.  However, let's try it anyway:

```
data(trees)
df <- transform(trees,
            h=Height * 0.3048,   #transform to metric system
            dbh=Girth * 0.3048 / pi   #transform tree girth to diameter
            )
lm(1/(h-1.3) ~ poly(I(1/dbh),2,raw=TRUE),data=df)

## Coefficients:
##                    (Intercept)  poly(I(1/dbh), 2, raw = TRUE)1  
##                       0.043502                       -0.006136  
## poly(I(1/dbh), 2, raw = TRUE)2  
##                       0.010792
```

These results would normally be good enough to get good starting values for the `nls` fit.  However, you can do better than that via `glm`, which uses a link function to allow for some forms of non-linearity.  Specifically,

```
(fit2 <- glm(h-1.3 ~ poly(I(1/dbh),2,raw=TRUE),
             family=gaussian(link="inverse"),data=df))

## Coefficients:
##                    (Intercept)  poly(I(1/dbh), 2, raw = TRUE)1  
##                       0.041795                       -0.002119  
## poly(I(1/dbh), 2, raw = TRUE)2  
##                       0.008175  
## 
## Degrees of Freedom: 30 Total (i.e. Null);  28 Residual
## Null Deviance:       113.2 
## Residual Deviance: 80.05     AIC: 125.4 
##
```

You can see that the results are *approximately* the same as the linear fit, but not quite.

```
pframe <- data.frame(dbh=seq(0.8,2,length=51))
```

We use `predict`, but need to correct the prediction to account for the fact that we subtracted a constant from the LHS:

```
pframe$h <- predict(fit2,newdata=pframe,type="response")+1.3
p2 <- predict(fit2,newdata=pframe,se.fit=TRUE) ## predict on link scale
pframe$h_lwr <- with(p2,1/(fit+1.96*se.fit))+1.3
pframe$h_upr <- with(p2,1/(fit-1.96*se.fit))+1.3
png("dbh_tmp1.png",height=4,width=6,units="in",res=150)
par(las=1,bty="l")
plot(h~dbh,data=df)
with(pframe,lines(dbh,h,col=2))
with(pframe,polygon(c(dbh,rev(dbh)),c(h_lwr,rev(h_upr)),
      border=NA,col=adjustcolor("black",alpha=0.3)))
dev.off()
```

[image]

Because we have used the constant on the LHS (this almost, but doesn't quite, fit into the framework of using an *offset* -- we could only use an offset if our formula were `1/H - 1.3 = a/D^2 + ...`, i.e. if the constant adjustment were on the link (inverse) scale rather than the original scale), this doesn't fit perfectly into `ggplot`'s `geom_smooth` framework

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(df,aes(dbh,h))+geom_point()+theme_bw()+
   geom_line(data=pframe,colour="red")+
   geom_ribbon(data=pframe,colour=NA,alpha=0.3,
             aes(ymin=h_lwr,ymax=h_upr))

ggsave("dbh_tmp2.png",height=4,width=6)
```

[image]