# R linear regression

Tags: r

I have the formula y = x / (a+b*x) that I want to fit to the points (6,72) (211,183) (808,360) (200,440).  I put them in R using

```
x <- c(6,211,808,200)
y <- c(72,183,360,440)
```

Now I want to the fit the function defined above to fit trough these points, and find a and b.
How do I get a and b (using R) ? and, how do i get the formula in R?

Comment: This is not linear regression.  You can use `nls(y~x/(a+b*x), ...` (you'll have to provide starting values) or `glm(y~x,family=gaussian(link="inverse"))`.  See related (but harder than this): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073246/how-to-put-a-complicated-equation-into-a-r-formula/15076688#15076688

Answer (score 2):

Get the data and plot it:

```
x <- c(6,211,808,200)
y <- c(72,183,360,440)
plot(x,y,pch=19)
```

Define the function, get your coefficients

```
f <- function(x,a,b) {x/(a+b*x)}
fit <- nls(y ~ f(x,a,b), start=c(a=1,b=1))
co <- coef(fit)
# co will contain your coefficients for a and b
#          a           b 
#0.070221853 0.002796513
```

And plot away:

```
curve(f(x, a=co["a"], b=co["b"]), add = TRUE, col="green", lwd=2)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: very nice answer, but the OP's model is **not** `x/(a+b+x)`, it's `x/(a+b*x)` -- which is not overparameterized, although fitting a 2-parameter model to 4 data points is a little dicey ...

Comment: @BenBolker - damn! That's what you get for answering at midnight. I learnt a few things when researching my old answer anyway, so it wasn't a total loss. Edited for the new answer...

Answer (score 2):

Construct data:

```
x <- c(6,211,808,200)
y <- c(72,183,360,440)
d <- data.frame(x,y)
```

Plot the data: although sparse, they're not insane (they do show some evidence of an increasing/saturating pattern)

```
plot(y~x,data=d)
```

Fit the model:

```
## y = x/(a+b*x)
## 1/y = a/x + b
m1 <- glm(y~I(1/x),family=gaussian(link="inverse"),data=d)
```

You can plot the results in `ggplot`

```
library("ggplot2")
qplot(x,y,data=d)+theme_bw()+
    geom_smooth(method="glm",family=gaussian(link="inverse"),
                formula=y~I(1/x),se=FALSE)
```

The confidence intervals for this model are somewhat crazy (because the confidence intervals for `1/y` include zero, at which point the confidence intervals on `y` blow up), so be careful ...