# Get Least Square Estimator in R

Tags: r, optimization, least-squares

I have a problem of finding least square estimator. The background is:

```
`v = beta3*(1 - exp(1 - k_star/k))`

`k_star = 1/(beta0 + beta1*v + beta2*v^2)`
```

I want to get the least square estimators, see the obj. func. below.

The dataset could be find in the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ywo5pkh5jptr2g/samp.csv?dl=0).

The objective function is to minimize:

```
    G(beta)=(k_i - 1/(beta0+beta1*v_i+beta2*v_i^2)(1-log(1-v_i/beta3)))^2
```

I tried to use code like below, but not succeed:

```
k_v <- function(beta){
    beta0 = beta[1]
    beta1 = beta[2]
    beta2 = beta[3]
    beta3 = beta[4]
    denomi1 = beta0 + beta1*samp$mean_speed 
    + beta2*samp$mean_speed^2
    denomi2 = 1 - log(1 - samp$mean_speed / beta3)
    (samp$density - 1 / denomi1 * denomi2)^2
  }

beta_init <- c(1.5, 0.5, -0.013, 140)
opti_params <- optim(par = beta_init, fn = k_v)
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction, please!

Thanks.

Comment: Why use `optim` instead of `nls`?

Comment: @Gregor, haven't use that before, will take a look at that now!

Comment: An old question that might help out [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15073246/903061).

Comment: @Gregor, I tried like the example you pointed. But got the error of "step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562"